# Performance degradation inserting from SQL Server 2012 to DB2 z/os

Tags: sql-server, performance, db2, linked-server, zos

We're inserting data into a table from SQL Server 2012 Linked Server with the latest DB2 OLEDB Driver to DB2 z/os.

Inserting data into a table with more then 38 columns drastically decreases the performance (see picture below). It doesnt seem to be an issue with the actual amount of characters, but rather the amount of columns.

We've tried inserting less data into the table (instead of filling a 1 CHAR column, we filled a 32 CHAR column). This works fine as long as we don't pass the limit of 38 columns. For testing, all rows were CHAR, variating in size from 1 to 132. We've tried inserting with openquery, however this did not resolve the issue.

The column can be a 1 CHAR column, a DECIMAL, DATE or VARCHAR. The issue remains the same. I'd also like to add that the table has no constraints or trigger which could interfere.

[image: db2 z/os column insert performance]

Tips, ideas and suggestions are welcome!

**UPDATE:**
We've tried doing the same with SQL Server 2008. The same issue occurred, however this time the performance dropped when inserting data into a table with more then 20 columns. We've also contacted Microsoft about this issue, response is pending.

Comment: never ever seen issue like this, I think you'll have to use some diagnostic tools. I would start with a comparing execution plans for the queries, or SQL Profiler for example, to see what's really executing on the server

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've already looked at what is executing on the target database but we didn't find anything special. We'll take you advice and take a  closer look at the source database to see if we can isolate the issue!

Comment: Interesting. It could be maybe bug, make sure that you have the newest service pack installed and the sql server is well updated. Otherwise I would try to contact Microsoft support

Comment: Does inserting > 38 columns but with fewer rows make a difference? That is, if you're inserting the same number of rows each time, the total number of bytes increases. Does reducing the number of bytes push the speed back up?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly, no.... inserting 1000 or 1 000 000 rows made no difference in performance when data was inserted in > 38 columns.